# How to place component in the header with lazy loading?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my vue application, how to place component (slot?) in the toolbar component?

My app for example:

```
<template>
  <toolbar>…</toolbar>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

and all the routes are lazy loaded.

for some routes I want to place component inside toolbar component. But I can't "insert" the component as slot. and to write the component and turn on/off with `v-if` seems to me wrong.

I think that I expect is

```
 <div for="toolbar">This content should in toolbar</div>
 <div for="router-view">This content for router-view</div>
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It depends.  Is the content coming from and/or controlled by the child component?

Answer (score 1):

Vue Router [Named Views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#named-views) will come in handy.

> Sometimes you need to display multiple views at the same time instead
>   of nesting them, e.g. creating a layout with a `sidebar` view and a `main`
>   view. This is where named views come in handy. Instead of having one
>   single outlet in your view, you can have multiple and give each of
>   them a name. A `router-view` without a name will be given `default` as its
>   name.

A view is rendered by using a component, therefore multiple views require multiple components for the same route. Make sure to use the `components` (**with an** `s`) option:

```
<template>
  <toolbar><router-view name="toolbar"></router-view></toolbar>
  <router-view />
</template>


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: YourAwesomeComponent,
        toolbar: YetAnotherAwesomeComponent
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      components: {
        default: YourAwesomeHomeComponent,
        toolbar: YetAnotherAwesomeComponentThatSouldBeInToolbarOnHomePage
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Great solution. but what if I want to communicate between them? like I have button close or open whatever on default component?

Comment: Use Vuex or Event Bus.